# multiple prints from same button? html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input fields and a submit button, onclick the button displays the inputs on the webpage. When i type a new message it only displays this, it removes the old one. How can i click the button and still have the old message with the new one?

```js
function outputdisplayname(){
            var x, y, z;
            x = document.getElementById('form1');
            y = x.elements["name"].value;
            z = x.elements["message"].value;

            document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=y;
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML=z;
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<form id = "form1">
        Name: <input name = "name" type = "text" size = "20" id = "text1"/>
        Message: <input name = "message" type = "text" size ="20" id = "text2"/>
</form>

<button onclick="outputdisplayname()">Display</button>

<p id = "demo1"></p>
<p id = "demo2"></p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answers are good but it will end up looking something like this:

```
<p id = "demo1"> NameA NameB NameC</p>
<p id = "demo2">  Message1  Message2  Message3</p>
```

While you might want something like this:

```
<div id="messages">

<h4> Name1 </h4>
<p> Message1 </p>

<h4> Name2 </h4>
<p> Message2 </p>

<h4> Name3 </h4>
<p> Message3 </p>

</div>
```

For that you just have to replace:

```
<p id = "demo1"></p>
<p id = "demo2"></p>
```

With

```
<div id="messages"> </div>
```

And replace this:

```
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=y;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML=z;
```

With:

```
newmsg = "<h4> "+ y +" </h4> <p> "+ z +" </p>";
document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += newmsg;
```

"+=" works as if you are doing something like: x += y ==  x = x + y
Also, you don't have to worry about the spacing because the "p" and "h" tags take care of it, you could add some css classes into it, though.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = y;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += y;
```

You only have to make sure that `demo1` is empty before clicking the button.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the output to display on a new line instead of side by side?

Comment: Add a `<br>` tag before appending `y`: 

`document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += '<br>' += y;`

Comment: This only moves the message to a new line? How do I get each name and message together and the next input on a new line? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To keep the previous message use `+=` instead of `=`.

Change

```
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=y;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML=z;
```

To

```
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += "<br>" + y; // br element to display message in new line.
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += "<br>" + z;
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I get the output to display on a new line rather than side by side?

Comment: @JayMac, you can add `br` element for that, updated the answer please check.

Comment: This only moves the message to a new line? How do I get each name and message together and the next input on a new line? thanks!

Comment: @JayMac, I think you do not need two *p* for that. You can try with single element like: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br>" + y + "  " + z;`

Answer (score 0):

To maintain old values and new values. use JS concat with `+` symbol. like the following code.

> you need to add br tag to print in new line.

```
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += "<br/>"+y;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += "<br/>"+z;
```

```js
          function outputdisplayname(){
            var x, y, z;
            x = document.getElementById('form1');
            y = x.elements["name"].value;
            z = x.elements["message"].value;

            document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += "<br/>"+y;
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += "<br/>"+z;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><img src="img/header.png"  alt="header and logo"/></head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
          body {
                    background-color: lightgrey;
            }

        </style>
    <body>
             <div style="text-align:left">
            <div class="nav"><a class="active" href="mypage.html"><h4>My Page</a></h4>
            <div class="nav"><a class="active" href="index.html"><h4>Home</a></h4>
            </div>  
            <h1>Blog</h1>
            <p>this is the live blog where users can post updates and communicate with each other</p> 

        <form id = "form1">
        Name: <input name = "name" type = "text" size = "20" id = "text1"/>
        Message: <input name = "message" type = "text" size ="20" id = "text2"/>
         </form>

        <button onclick="outputdisplayname()">Display</button>

        <p id = "demo1"></p>
        <p id = "demo2"></p>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When we write `int a =10;` and next line again `a=50;` that finnally a contant 50 as the mase like this is containt jsut `y` value  `document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=y;`.

you can write following code here,

```
var y = '<p>this is successful message</p>';

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML + y;
```

**Same as**

```
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += y;
```